# What are the Wolfram Mathematica NDSolve function methods?

Tags: numerical-methods, mathematica

What are the Wolfram Mathematica NDSolve function methods? I know that in Wolfram Mathematica I can specify solving method in NDSolve function, but I can't find a full list of available methods in documentation.

Comment: Note that the NDSolve's documentation [page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html?q=NDSolve&lang=en) is available on-line. You can find the list of methods by clicking "More Information".

Comment: You could find [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3151/204) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3372/204) useful as well! Good luck! ... could someone please correct how my hyperlink code looks like here? I just hate that!

Comment: better question for http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are some of the methods:

`"Adams"` - predictor-corrector Adams method with orders 1 through 12

`"BDF"` - Gear implicit backward differentiation formulas with orders 1 through 5

[`"ExplicitRungeKutta"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveExplicitRungeKutta.html) - adaptive embedded pairs of 2(1) through 9(8) Runge-Kutta methods

[`"ImplicitRungeKutta"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveImplicitRungeKutta.html) - families of arbitrary-order implicit Runge-Kutta methods

[`"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveSPRK.html) - interleaved Runge-Kutta methods for separable Hamiltonian systems

[`"MethodOfLines"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePDE.html) - method of lines for solution of PDEs

[`"Extrapolation"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveExtrapolation.html) - (Gragg-)Bulirsch-Stoer extrapolation method, with possible submethods

- `"ExplicitEuler"` - forward Euler method
- `"ExplicitMidpoint"` - midpoint rule method
- `"ExplicitModifiedMidpoint"` - midpoint rule method with Gragg smoothing
- `"LinearlyImplicitEuler"` - linearly implicit Euler method
- `"LinearlyImplicitMidpoint"` - linearly implicit midpoint rule method
- `"LinearlyImplicitModifiedMidpoint"` - linearly implicit Bader-smoothed midpoint rule method

[`"DoubleStep"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveDoubleStep.html) - "baby" version of `"Extrapolation"`

`"LocallyExact"` - numerical approximation to locally exact symbolic solution

[`"StiffnessSwitching"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessSwitching.html) - allows switching between nonstiff and stiff methods in the middle of the integration

[`"Projection"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveProjection.html) - invariant-preserving method

[`"OrthogonalProjection"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveOrthogonalProjection.html) - method that preserves orthonormality of solutions

[`"IDA"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveIDAMethod.html) - general purpose solver for the initial value problem for systems of differential-algebraic equations (DAEs)

[`"Shooting"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html#659822336) - shooting method for BVPs

[`"Chasing"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html#948663323) - Gelfand-Lokutsiyevskii chasing method for BVPs

[`"EventLocator"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveEventLocator.html) - event location for detecting discontinuities, periods, etc.

Comment: Mathematica 10 and beyond : `FiniteElements` . A big step forward.

Comment: The first method was `"LSODA"` and it's still the default ODE method.  There are also `"Splitting"`, `"Composition"`, `"StabilizedRungeKutta"`, `"Parareal"`; and `"Streamline"`, `"SensitivityMethod"`, which seem to be used internally only.